# firebase functions + realtime database - database structure and code

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I'm on a simple application:
It's my first try with firebase functions + realtime database.

The functions are going to be called by an external client application (e.g.: android).

if it was not javascript + nosqldb I would not have a problem, but here I am stuck, because I'm not sure for the best db structure and about transaction-like operations.

I. **stored data:**

- user profile (id, fullname, email, phone, photo)
- tickets amount per user
- history for tickets buyings
- history for tickets usings

II. **actions:**

- user buy some tickets - should add tickets to the user's amount AND add a record to buyings history
- user use some tickets - should remove tickets from the user's amount AND add a record to usings history

So my base problem is this ANDs - if it was a SQL db i would use a transaction but here I'm not sure what is db structure and js code in order to achieve same result.

**EDITED:**
======== index.js =======

```
exports.addTickets = functions.https.onCall((data, context) => {
 // data comes from client app
 const buyingRecord = data;
 console.log(‘buyingRecord: ‘ + JSON.stringify(buyingRecord));

return tickets.updateTicketsAmmount(buyingRecord)
 .then((result)=>{
 tickets.addTicketsBuyingRecord(buyingRecord);
 result.userid = buyingRecord.userid;
 result.ticketsCount = buyingRecord.ticketsCount;
 return result;
 });
});
```

====== tickets.js =======

```
exports.updateTicketsAmmount = function(buyingRecord) {
 var userRef = db.ref(‘users/’ + buyingRecord.userid);
 var amountRef = db.ref(‘users/’ + buyingRecord.userid + ‘/ticketsAmount’);
 return amountRef.transaction((current)=>{
 return (current || 0) + buyingRecord.ticketsCount;
 })
 .then(()=>{
 console.log(“amount updated for userid [“ + buyingRecord.userid + “]”);
 return userRef.once(‘value’);
 })
 .then((snapshot)=>{
 var data = snapshot.val();
 console.log(“data for userid [“ + snapshot.key + “]:” + JSON.stringify(data));
 return data;
 });
}

exports.addTicketsBuyingRecord = function(buyingRecord) {
 var historyRef = db.ref(‘ticketsBuyingHistory’);
 var newRecordRef = historyRef.push();
 return newRecordRef.set(buyingRecord)
 .then(()=>{
 console.log(‘history record added.’); 
 return newRecordRef.once(‘value’);
 })
 .then((snapshot)=>{
 var data = snapshot.val();
 console.log(‘data:’ + JSON.stringify(data));
 return data;
 });
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You would have to use the callback, the request on Android to add or read data have an onSuccess or OnFailure CallBack, i used this to trigger my new request.

You can check this on the doc [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/read-and-write?authuser=0#add_a_completion_callback) :)

Also if instead of using RealTime Database you use Firestore you can use the FireStore Transactions here is the [info](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/transactions?authuser=0).

Comment: I've updated my question with database structure and js code. I'm trying to use Promises but currently no luck with that.

Comment: Hey, ok would you mind share your log if you have one, or to explain what´s the function doing and where exactly are you stuck, Thanks

Comment: Sorry for the latency. I've updated the source code in the question.
I think it's better now.

    1. updates the tickets amount using a transaction on this level
    2. adds a buying record.

But still I'm sure what if step1 succeeds and step2 fails.
The data would be somekind inconsistent: updated count witout corresponding record.
I'm not sure if using transaction on such a low level in nosql db is a good idea.

Comment: sorry, I meant "still I'm not sure" in the last comment but I can edit it no more.